# How to say "may get a refund or need to pay more later" succinctly?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

If a customer asks a company to do a project, but both customer and company don't know the exact amount of money needed, so the company just tells the customer:

> Give me $X first, we will rebate you if we don't use that much, and if the cost exceeds $X you will need to pay the extra."

How to say this naturally and succinctly?

Comment: "...You may get a refund or be required to pay extra."

Comment: "Give me $X up front, and we'll refund you what we don't use, or bill you the difference if it costs more."

Answer (score -3):

I think the sentence would look like this. It is not sure.
Please give us guarantee for $X. When budget of the project aren't suitable to money, we will give refund or get some extra money.

Comment: This is not idiomatic English.

Comment: That's not even correct English